# Functional component with React.memo() still rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle, react-memo

I have a button component that has a button inside that has a state passed to it `isActive` and a click function. When the button is clicked, the `isActive` flag will change and depending on that, the app will fetch some data. The button's parent component does not rerender. I have searched on how to force stop rerendering for a component and found that `React.memo(YourComponent)` must do the job but still does not work in my case. It also make sense to pass a check function for the memo function whether to rerender or not which I would set to false all the time but I cannot pass another argument to the function. Help.

button.tsx

```
interface Props {
    isActive: boolean;
    onClick: () => void;
}

const StatsButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ isActive, onClick }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('RERENDER');
    }, []);

    return (
        <S.Button onClick={onClick} isActive={isActive}>
            {isActive ? 'Daily stats' : 'All time stats'}
        </S.Button>
    );
};

export default React.memo(StatsButton);
```

parent.tsx

```
const DashboardPage: React.FC = () => {

const {
        fetchDailyData,
        fetchAllTimeData,
    } = useDashboard();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCountry();
        fetchAllTimeData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    const handleClick = useEventCallback(() => {
        if (!statsButtonActive) {
            fetchDailyData();
        } else {
            fetchAllTimeData();
        }
        setStatsButtonActive(!statsButtonActive);
    });

return (
  <S.Container>
            <S.Header>
                <StatsButton
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    isActive={statsButtonActive}
                />
            </S.Header>
</S.Container>
)

}
```

fetch functions are using `useCallback`

```
export const useDashboard = (): Readonly<DashboardOperators> => {
    const dispatch: any = useDispatch();

    const fetchAllTimeData = useCallback(() => {
        return dispatch(fetchAllTimeDataAction());
    }, [dispatch]);

    const fetchDailyData = useCallback(() => {
        return dispatch(fetchDailyDataAction());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return {
        fetchAllTimeData,
        fetchDailyData,
    } as const;
};
```

Comment: Along with useMemo you would want to wrap your onClick in a useCallback. Since it is a function, it will be created fresh on every render. React.memo does shallow comparison

Comment: Did you realize that `console.log('RERENDER');` will run not just on _re-renders_ but also on initial renders? Just want to make sure you're not getting a false read that re-renders are actually happening.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't posted all of `parent.tsx`, but I assume that `handleClick` is created within the body of the parent component. Because the identity of the function will be different on each rendering of the parent, that causes `useMemo` to see the props as having changed, so it will be re-rendered.

Depending on if what's referenced in that function is static, you *may* be able to use `useCallback` to pass the same function reference to the component on each render.

Note that there is an RFC for something *even better* than `useCallback`; if `useCallback` doesn't work for you look at how [`useEvent`](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md) is defined for an idea of how to make a better static function reference. It looks like that was even published as a new [`use-event-callback`](https://github.com/Volune/use-event-callback) package.

**Update**:

It sounds like `useCallback` won't work for you, presumably because the referenced variables used by the callback change on each render, causing `useCallback` to return different values, thus making the prop different and busting the cache used by `useMemo`. Try that `useEventCallback` approach. Just to illustrate how it all works, here's a naive implementation.

```
function useEventCallback(fn) {
  const realFn = useRef(fn);

  useEffect(() => {
    realFn.current = fn;
  }, [fn]);

  return useMemo((...args) => {
    realFn.current(...args)
  }, []);
}
```

This `useEventCallback` always returns the same memoized function, so you'll pass the same value to your props and not cause a re-render. However, when the function is called it calls the version of the function passed into `useEventCallback` instead. You'd use it like this in your parent component:

```
const handleClick = useEventCallback(() => {
  if (!statsButtonActive) {
    fetchDailyData();
  } else {
    fetchAllTimeData();
  }
  setStatsButtonActive(!statsButtonActive);
});
```

Comment: can you provide an example of `useCallback`? I have updated the parent component code

Comment: I have updated the code using `useCallback` and it still rerenders

Comment: You haven't shown where that function's _dependencies_ are declared. If the dependencies change then a new version of the function is returned and will thwart your efforts to memoize. Look into that `useEventCallback` alternative. That approach _always_ returns the same function that you can use with props but uses a ref to call a _real_ underlying function that is updated with any closed over variables without needing to specify a dependencies array.

Comment: still does not work. It works fine fi I remove fetch functions.

Comment: you can also check how `useDashboard` is implemented in the update

Comment: also, if the parent does not rerender it means that the function is the same I assume. Which means that I done need to memoize the function?